# Webpack and boostrap, remove styles from style tag

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I'm new with Webpack. Using webpack 4.26.
I was trying to install bootstrap. I'v install it but css styles wasn't build in a separate file. I'v solved this problem and now my config looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'app.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(scss)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|gif)$/,
                exclude: /svg[\/\\]/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: 'images/[name].[ext]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'style.css',
        })
    ]
};
```

Index.js:

```
'use strict'

import 'bootstrap';
import './index.scss';
```

index.scss

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

So now I have a separate file 'style.css' with all bootstrap styles, but, as I understand styles still included to bundle and rendered into  tag.
How can I remove it from bundle?

Comment: " I understand styles still included to bundle and rendered into tag" - No, they are not. They would be if you were using style-loader.

Comment: @PlayMa256 But in this case whe there is a style tag?

Comment: you should add to you html. This workflow is usually used only for production but in conjunction with html-webpack-plugin which will add those files automatically.

Comment: @PlayMa256 Sorry, there is a typo in my comment, I mean not where, but why. No I see styles in a bundle. So it is included in it.

Comment: oh, now it makes sense. Probably because bootstrap imports a CSS file, not an scss. You need to add the same rule as you did for scss for css, removing postcss and sass loaders